# Not able to access /dev/block/sdbx in system app?

Tags: updates, partitions

is it possible to copy /dev/block/sdax to /dev/block/sday in c++ with using system call,
example this should happen

```
dd if=/dev/block/sdb20 of=/dev/block/sdb43 bs=4096
```

without using `system()`?

I am not able to access /dev/block even though handled avc denials in repective .te file and running in permissive ?

```
01-01 00:00:04.259  4173  4173 I update_engine: type=1400 audit(0.0:319): avc: denied { read } for name="sdb43" dev="tmpfs" ino=13472 scontext=u:r:update_engine:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
01-01 00:00:04.259  4173  4173 I update_engine: type=1400 audit(0.0:320): avc: denied { open } for path="/dev/block/sdb43" dev="tmpfs" ino=13472 scontext=u:r:update_engine:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
01-01 00:00:04.259  4173  4173 I update_engine: type=1400 audit(0.0:321): avc: denied { write } for name="sdb46" dev="tmpfs" ino=1142 scontext=u:r:update_engine:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
01-01 00:00:04.259  4173  4173 I update_engine: type=1400 audit(0.0:322): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/dev/block/sdb43" dev="tmpfs" ino=13472 scontext=u:r:update_engine:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
01-01 00:00:04.146
```